# How to find a word in a string (not only index)?

Tags: python

This is my assignment:

```
# text = input()
# word = input()
# print(search(text, word))
```

I need to print "Word found" if word there is in text. And "Word not found" if doesn't.

How I tried:

1. First attempt:

   ```
   text = input()
   word = input()
   def search(text, word):
       if text.split() in word.split():
           print("Word found")
       else:
           print("Word not found")
   search(text, word)
   ```
2. Second attempt:

   ```
   def search(text, word):
       if word.find() == text.find():
           print ("!")
       else:
           print("?")
   search(text, word)
   ```
3. Third attempt:

   ```
   text = input()
   word = input()
   def answer(text, word):
       if text.find(word):
           True
           print("!")
       else:
           print("?")
   answer(text, word)
   ```

Comment: Try `if word in text:`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `in`:

```
def search(text, word):
    if word in text:
        print("Word found")
    else:
        print("Word not found")

text = input()
word = input()

search(text, word)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
text = input()
word = input()
def search(t, w):
  return "Word found" if t in w else return "Word not found"

print(search(text, word))
```

i think this could be a solution for you, if you think it's best you can have a normal if else instead of the ternary if as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
S = "find the word"
if "word" in S
```